# In iOS start apple maps navigation and let it close again, when destination is reached

Tags: ios, navigation, maps

I know that you can launch an Apple maps navigation session from within another app.

Is it possible, when the destination is reached, to come back to the app that launched it?

Comment: NO. But yes if you can implement navigation in your application

Comment: could you rephrase your question so that the problem and the question are more readily understandable

Comment: @iphonic You should expand slightly and add that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

NO, because the other application(`GoogleMap/iOS Map application`) is not programmed to open your application, you can't achieve it this way.

Though there is a way, if you implement navigation in you application, using [google apis](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). And this way you can achieve what you want after a destination has reached.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleMap or Apple Map Application won't allow you to move back to your app automatically. You will need to go manually.